# How to parse fullfilment response from dialogflow correctly in java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

As you know in Dialogflow when we are using fulfillment, there can be more than a type of response inside a single response such as basic card, suggestion, simple respond, link out suggestion, etc. How to parse this response correctly so we can have a clear Object/JSONObject that distinguished each type of responses to be used later on. I was thinking is there any way that I can parse it to be something like this

```
{
  simpleRespond:[{text:"Hello},{text:hi}],
  basicCard:[{title:"MyCard",subTitle:"When I was in school",image:{text:"hi",URL:"photo.jpg"}}],
  suggestion:[{text:"banana"},{text:"Apple"}]
  and other response
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To know how to properly fill a [webhook response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response), with multiple messages and with different types, I think you can focus on the `fulfillment_messages[]` [field](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookresponse).

*Notice that I'm using the WebhookResponse V2 RPC [reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/common-types#webhookresponse).*

You can see that the `fulfillment_messages[]` field can contain a list of `Message` [objects](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#message), which structure is like the following:

```
{
  "text": {
    "text": [
      "Text response from webhook"
    ]
  }
}
```

Where the `text` object is a rich response message, and can be only one of the specified in the [reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#message).

Based on this, you could prepare the `fulfillment_messages[]` field from the WebhookResponse object like the following:

```
{
  "fulfillment_messages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Message object sample 1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "card": {
        "title": "card title",
        "subtitle": "Message object sample 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Message object sample 3"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** the actual final result of using this list and how is handled by Dialogflow, may not be the desired for you, so I suggest you to do some testing to get an idea how Dialogflow will handle them. For what I know, Dialogflow may do a couple of things here, it may try to put them together, or it may select a random message.